# How to switch user or lock PC via keyboard shortcut manjaro XFCE

Tags: xfce, manjaro

How do I lock my manjaro XFCE based PC with a keyboard shortcut i.e. like WIN+L on a windows machine.

All guidance I can find is gnome specific i.e.

```
gnome-screensaver-command --lock
```

Comment: for whom come from G, this is my solution, create bash script with these lines (two lines not single one )   `xfce4-screensaver >/dev/null 2>&1 &
xfce4-screensaver-command --lock` add application keyboard shortcut to activate e.g when pressing `Win+L`

Answer (score 2):

Whilst not technically a duplicate, the other question DID include the answer. The command I needed to assign to a keyboard shortcut was:

```
xflock4
```